# My Wordpress feed isn't working for a certain category. Getting a 404 error for pageurl.com/post/feed/. How do I fix?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, rss, custom-wordpress-pages

All the pages in my "FAQ" section seem to have a 404 error for their feeds. I'm not sure if the feed is not being generated or if it's being generated on another URL.

I noticed the error in Google's search console. I have a bunch of 404 errors for my feed pages.

Here's an example - https://www.insurancepanda.com/faq/state-farm-towing-cost/ works and the feed should be https://www.insurancepanda.com/faq/state-farm-towing-cost/feed/

The following code appears in the page heading, calling up the feed.

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Insurance Panda &raquo; How Much Does State Farm Charge for Towing? Comments Feed" href="https://www.insurancepanda.com/faq/state-farm-towing-cost/feed/" />
```

Any ideas how to fix? If this isn't important and has no SEO benefit, is there an easy way to remove this feed URL from my FAQ pages? (it works on other sections of. my site)

Thanks!

I've beeen looking in WP-ADMIN for the RSS feed settings, but I can't find them.

I also can't seem to find where to edit the "link rel" code in the functions.php section or the header.php section of my theme.